# Deleting Duplicate Rows in a TVF (Can't use Temp Tables or CTE)

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

We have a system using a Table Value Function in SQL 2k5 that gathers all of the products that are available to a user and return the IDs and Prices.  The problem is that sometimes multiple vendors will offer the same products.  So we need to eliminate the duplicates except for the lowest priced item.

The problem is that I'm working in a TVF.  So I cannot use a Temporary Table, I can't use CTE, I can't load and delete from any outside tables, I can't even use (gasp!) dynamic SQL in any way.  I can only work in the defined return table.

I can identify these duplicates but I can't figure out a single DELETE statement I can run on @productTable to delete the duplicate products while keeping one of them that has the lowest price.

So my example below is simplified but this his the basic premise, the IDENTIFY DUPLICATES section should basically be a single statement DELETE on @productTable to remove these duplicates.

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf_UserProducts] 
(
    @userID uniqueidentifier
)

RETURNS @productTable TABLE 
(
    productID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    model varchar(50),
    upc varchar(20),
    price money
)

INSERT INTO @productTable(productID, model, upc, price)
SELECT productID, model, upc, price
FROM tProducts
  ..... INTERNAL LOGIC TO GET THE RIGHT PRODUCTS ....
WHERE userID=@userID

--IDENTIFY DUPLICATES
SELECT productID, price, COUNT(productID) OVER (PARTITION BY upc) AS upcDupes
FROM @productTable
WHERE upc<>''
ORDER BY upc

RETURN
```

Comment: Why is this a multi-statement TVF instead of an inline TVF? What does a duplicate really mean here? Can you show sample data, current results, and desired results? Currently this just seems like "why isn't this code working" and we have no idea what "working" means to you. You don't *DELETE* duplicates from a table-valued function. What you should be focusing on is how to prevent duplicates from going in there in the first place.

Comment: It's easy. You fix your *INTERNAL LOGIC TO GET THE RIGHT PRODUCTS* to **only get the right products**, which means there are no duplicates to begin with because you've not included them. I can't tell you how to do that, though, because you failed to provide the *INTERNAL LOGIC* that you're using now, your table schema, and some sample data and output.

Comment: I appreciate the simplicity of fixing my internal logic.  However, I have severely simplified this function to just narrow down to the problem.  The logic is actually much more complex.  The return of products is based on a complex authorization system, it includes a bunch of tables to add and delete custom products and brands, each with its own price range, and on and on and on.  I am bound by the TVF that we're in and can't do anything outside of it so I find myself with this large dataset that then needs to be whittled down.

Comment: Also, I am using the price example but there are actually 3 separate tie breakers.  Price, Preferred Suppliers, Preferred Ship Source.  There is a whole configuration system that allows the user to choose which tie breakers to use and in which order.  So they may say break tie by price first, then supplier, then source.  They may say Source, then price, then supplier.  So I need to load all of my products then run 3 separate DELETE statements to remove duplicates in the correct order.  I have this logic all worked out using GOTO statements.  But I can't figure out the actual delete statements.

Comment: Don't simplify to the extent you change the question. "bound by the TVF that we're in and can't do anything outside of it" is not clear.

Comment: Once you take a table function and make it multi statement the performance goes down the toilet.

Comment: Believe me I know, not every choice can be made in a vacuum. Fortunately this is not a high impact procedure and is run maybe a couple times a day by a few people as opposed to our search functions running thousands and thousands of times a day.  I think my mistake was in minimizing the complexity of the business logic in my original question.  I was trying to be succinct but perhaps that just caused more confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question states lowest price
Borrows from Linoff +1

```
INSERT INTO @productTable(productID, model, upc, price)
    SELECT productId, model, upc, price
    FROM (SELECT productID, model, upc, price,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY upc ORDER BY price asc) as seqnum
          FROM tProducts
            ..... INTERNAL LOGIC TO GET THE RIGHT PRODUCTS ....
          WHERE userID = @userID
            and upc <> ''
         ) pm
    WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Not clear at all from the question but appears cannot change the TVF
Then just use ROW_NUMBER() on the table variable

```
    SELECT productId, model, upc, price
    FROM (SELECT productID, model, upc, price,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY upc ORDER BY price asc) as seqnum
          FROM @productTable
          WHERE  upc <> ''
         ) pm
    WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: @AaronBertrand OK I agree

Comment: Please see my comment in two answers above, it relates to this as well.

Answer (score 3):

Don't remove the rows.  Just don't put them in to begin with:

```
INSERT INTO @productTable(productID, model, upc, price)
    SELECT productId, model, upc, price
    FROM (SELECT productID, model, upc, price,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY productId, price,
                                                 (case when upc <> '' then 1 else 2 end)
                                    ORDER BY (select NULL)) as seqnum
          FROM tProducts
            ..... INTERNAL LOGIC TO GET THE RIGHT PRODUCTS ....
          WHERE userID = @userID
         ) pm
    WHERE seqnum = 1 or upc = '';
```

It is unclear what you want when `upc = ''`, so this keeps all such rows regardless of duplicates (as implied by your question).

Comment: +1 Better yet: drop the insert and just make it an inline TVF that returns that SELECT...

Comment: Please see my comment above.  I simplified my example to narrow into the problem area.  There is a ton more business logic that forces me to use the method I'm using.  Believe me, i wish it was simpler.

Comment: This code below is almost working for me, it does do what i was looking for it to do.  However, when I have 2 prices that match instead of deleting one of them I need it to keep them both so it can cascade down to the next tie breaker.  This is deleting one of them.  Still working on that.

Answer (score 0):

Putting answer here to show the code that worked but I'll be sure to mark Blam's response as the correct answer.  This block below identifies and deletes all of my dupes.  Thanks for all the great responses!

```
DELETE FROM #productTable WHERE productID IN 
(SELECT productID 
    FROM
        (SELECT DISTINCT productID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY upc ORDER BY price) AS sq
        FROM #productTable
        WHERE upc <> '') temp
    WHERE sq>1)
```

Comment: I kept matching prices out by adding MIN(price) OVER (PARTITION BY upc) AS minPrice to the interior select statement and then adding AND price<>minPrice to the exterior where clause after sq>1.  This worked perfectly. Deletes my duplicates based on price but keeps duplicates if they're both of equal minimum price.